# With equal parts suspicion and fascination

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to add "of" to "[with equal parts suspicion and fascination](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/equal+parts.html)"  → "with equal parts of suspicion and fascination"?

Comment: You don't need the "of".

Comment: You don't need "of" - but the sentence does not sound entirely idiomatic to me anyway. It is correct that one would say "They sat eyeing me with both suspicion and fascination". But I would suggest that "equal parts" probably ought to take "in" rather than "with" - so it becomes "They sat eyeing me in equal parts, suspicion and fascination". But I would be interested to see what other, particularly British, native speakers think. Any thoughts @Kate Bunting?

Comment: Just to be clear I'd also be interested to see what Americans think - but selection of prepositions is where Anglo - American relations often part company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the "of" is not incorrect, but it is in no way requires, and it is more usual, and I would say more natural, to leave the "of" out in such a case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!